# Faut-il dire « merci de » ou « merci pour » ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, prépositions, politesse

J'ai l'habitude de remercier mon audience à la fin d'un exposé oral. Mais, dois-je les remercier **pour** leur attention ou **de** leur attention?

Concrètement, à la fin dois-je dire (et/ou écrire sur mes transparents):

> Merci pour votre attention.

ou

> Merci de votre attention.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Les deux se disent mais quand ce qui suit est un verbe à l'infinitif, *de* est de rigueur.  Donc

> remercier pour leur attention
>
> remercier de leur attention
>
> remercier d'avoir été attentif

mais pas

> remercier pour avoir été attentif

Comment: Merci d'avoir répondu ;-)

Comment: Heu... Pourquoi ne dit-on pas _Merci pour avoir été attentif_ ?                                                                                                                        ...(parce que moi je le dis)

Comment: @Istao, [« Devant un infinitif, si l'on a pu citer quelque exemple de pour, c'est de qui est d'usage. »](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/merci) (En passant, je doute que _quelque_ au singulier soit une erreur.)

Comment: @Unfrancophone Merci pour ta réponse. Effectivement, les deux se disent. Mais est-ce qu'il y a une formulation qui est plus correcte que l'autre?

Comment: @MarcelC. Pas que je sache.

Comment: Et [la pratique](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=merci+pour+votre%2Cmerci+de+votre%2Cmerci+d'avoir%2C+merci+pour+avoir&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19) confirme plutôt bien la théorie.

Answer (score 9):

Lors de l'emploi de *merci* ou du verbe *remercier* suivi d'un nom, je crois bien qu'il est d'usage de :

- faire suivre *merci* ou le verbe *remercier* par *de* si le nom renvoie à un sens abstrait. Exemple:

  > Ils le remercient de son aide

  ou encore :

  > Merci de ton aide
- faire suivre *merci* ou le verbe *remercier* par *pour* si le nom renvoie à un sens concret. Exemple:

  > Ils le remercient pour les chocolats

  ou :

  > Merci pour tes chocolats

Bonne écriture !

Answer (score 5):

Règle 1 : Lorsque « merci » est suivi d’un nom, vous avez le choix entre « de » et « pour ». Certaines personnes affirment cependant que l’usage de « de » se réfère plutôt au futur alors que celui de « pour » fait plus référence au passé. Girodet estime que « merci de » est utilisé dans un langage plus soutenu que « merci pour ». Une chose est sûre, l’Académie Française n’a pas tranché donc le choix reste libre !

Exemples : Merci de votre aide demain. Merci pour votre lettre qui est arrivée hier. Merci de votre attention / Merci pour votre attention.

Règle 2 : Lorsque « merci » précède un verbe à l’infinitif, alors il est TOUJOURS suivi de « de »  :

Exemples : Merci d’avoir écrit cette lettre. Merci de manger rapidement votre nourriture.

...
Pour plus d'informations : http://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/merci-pour-ou-merci-de

Answer (score 3):

Le [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_m&page=9MNFjlvlULPY.html#zz9MNFjlvlULPY) explique très bien les distinctions. D'abord, il y a la règle de base :

> Quand **merci** est suivi d’un nom, les prépositions **de** et **pour** sont
>   toutes deux correctes : *Merci de/pour ton aide. Merci du
>   compliment/pour le compliment. Merci pour le beau cadeau/du beau
>   cadeau.* Si **merci** est suivi d’un verbe à l’infinitif, c’est la
>   préposition **de** qui est obligatoire : *Merci d’être venue. Merci de
>   m’avoir accompagné.*

Puis, il y a des nuances :

> Bien que les deux prépositions soient acceptées lorsqu’elles sont
>   suivies d’un nom, on constate cependant que la préposition **de** est plus
>   fréquente avec un nom abstrait (bonté, aide, gentillesse, honnêteté,
>   etc.) : *Merci de votre collaboration. Merci de votre présence.* La
>   préposition **pour**, quant à elle, semble plus expressive, surtout devant
>   un nom concret : *Merci pour votre gentille lettre.* Quelques ouvrages
>   considèrent cet emploi de **pour** comme moins soutenu. Pourtant, devant
>   un nom pluriel comme dans *Merci pour les belles fleurs!*, la
>   préposition **pour** paraît inévitable.
>
> La même règle s’applique au verbe **remercier** : *Elle le remercie d’être
>   présent. Je te remercie de ton aide/pour ton aide.*

Comment: Merci, @Ange-à-Liberté ! C'est fait !

Answer (score 0):

*Merci pour* est dit aussi en espagnol: *gracias por su atención*. Je crois que « merci pour » vient de l'espagnol et non de l'anglais, mais je ne suis pas sûr.

Comment: Ce n'est pas le même usage, en français, il existe aussi bien "merci de" que "merci pour". Il faut savoir bien employer l'un ou l'autre quand il le faut. Ne pas dire ou écrire "merci pour" quand c'est "merci de" qui est correct dans le contexte.  "Merci pour" en français, ne vient pas de l'espagnol. Il est utilisé avant un nom.

Answer (score -1):

Absolument, il y a une formulation correcte et c'est le merci *de*.

> Merci d'être venu, merci d'avoir contribué à ceci, je vous remercie de votre attention, etc...

Le merci *pour* ne se dit, à ma connaissance, que dans le cas de l'expression « merci pour tout ».

En fait le « merci pour » ou le « remercier pour » est un anglo-germanisme qui vient de « danke(n) für » ou de « thank you for ».

Comment: En fait, « merci pour » est très courant. Il faut simplement googler « merci pour » pour voir ça.

Comment: I disagree, Ochado's right. "Merci de" et "Merci pour" n'ont pas le même usage. Quand c'est un verbe qui suit, bien sûr il faut utiliser "Merci de" (ex: Merci de fermer la portière), mais quand un nom suit, c'est le "Merci pour" qu'il faut utiliser. "Merci pour les chocolats" (comme l'exemple donné dans cette page.