# "Merci que" ou "merci de" ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, prépositions

Est-ce que c'est correct de dire : "Merci que vous êtes venus" ? Ou est-ce absolument faux et il faut dire : "Merci d'être venus" ?

Comment: Voir aussi: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/6437/176

Comment: Réponse simple:  Oui, merci que est absolument faux. Pourquoi ne pas le dire?

Answer (score 3):

Oui, c'est "Merci d'être venus", " Merci que vous êtes venus" sonne absolument faux. En France en tout cas !

Comment: Merci pour la réponse!

Answer (score 1):

On peut dire aussi bien "Merci de", "Merci pour" que "Merci à".

> **Merci d**'êtres venus
>
> **Merci pour** votre aide
>
> **Merci à** vous

Answer (score 0):

On peut aussi dire:

> Merci de votre visite.
>
> Merci d'être passé.